# Disabling Workbook Connections

Tags: vba

I have an Excel 2007 .xltm workbook template with several connections to SQL Server.  I did not list the xltm's directory as a Trusted Location, so by default, external connections were disabled.  This works well, because I have macros (signed & trusted) that would later enable these connections after a series of inputs using `Workbook_Open`.

However, I recently added the directory as a trusted location, and now the connections refresh automatically (regardless of `Connection.ODBCConnection.RefreshOnFileOpen` being set to `False`..)

So, I was hoping to find a simple command such as `ActiveWorkbook.DisableConnections` (since there is an `ActiveWorkbook.EnableConnections`...)

All I see is the read-only `ActiveWorkbook.ConnectionsDisabled`... How do I set it to true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out.  I run the following function once I'm done modifying the file, and this prevents the template from automatically refreshing the data.

```
Private Sub DisableConnections()
    Dim conn As Object
    For Each conn In ActiveWorkbook.Connections
        conn.ODBCConnection.EnableRefresh = False
    Next
End Sub
```

Depending on my setup, I might swap `ODBCConnection` for `OLEDBConnection`.