# ActiveWorkbook.ConnectionsDisabled is giving compile error

Tags: vba, excel, compilation, connection

I have written this code to enable connection:

```
Sub EnableConnection()

ActiveWorkbook.EnableConnections
answer = MsgBox("Connection enabled")

End Sub
```

and it works beautifully. However, when write the reverse:

```
Sub disableConnection()

ActiveWorkbook.ConnectionsDisabled

End Sub
```

I get Compile error:

> invalid use of Property

.

Can anyone help me fix this?

thank you in advance.

Comment: have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7843586/disabling-workbook-connnections)

Comment: I also want so that when the connection is disabled, the user is unable to refresh until connection is re-established.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code

```
ActiveWorkbook.ConnectionsDisabled
```

is a property, not a function. This means that it has a value, but it cannot do anything by itself. It just tells the status of the connection. To see what I mean, go to the immediate window of VBA and write     `?ActiveWorkbook.ConnectionsDisabled`
you would get either true or false, depending on the status.

Comment: Thanks Vityata and I see what you mean. What I want is a code that disables / suspends (but does not delete) the connection to prevent the user refreshing data after a certain point. Can you advise on that?

Comment: The link from @gizlmeier shows something like this, which should be working.